# iptables not letting SMTP through

Tags: smtp, iptables

I am trying to set up iptables to allow SMTP connections, and it does not seem to be working.

Here is the output of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8         reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:afs3-callback 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:3980 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:irdmi 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:microsoft-ds 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:hbci 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:hbci 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:irdmi 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp 

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

When I try to do `telnet host.address.com 25`, it says `Connection refused`. Connecting on other ports (for example, 80) works just fine. How do I figure out what's going on here?

EDIT:

Trying to connect on the machine to itself does work:

```
[root@machine user]# telnet 127.0.0.1 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 host.address.com ESMTP Postfix
```

EDIT 2:

Below is the output from `iptables-save`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Wed Oct 13 22:50:11 2010
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7001 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 137,138 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7002 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 139,445 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 13 22:50:11 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Wed Oct 13 22:50:11 2010
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3267:2601193]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1984:334831]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 13 22:50:11 2010
```

Comment: The output of `iptables -L` is likely not precise enough to allow reliable understanding of your iptables rules. What does `iptables-save` produce?

Comment: Maybe its postfix blocking all networks except localhost. I am assuming the iptables you are showing is on the postfix box, otherwise if not then you might want to see that servers firewall rules.

Comment: I was actually just looking at that. When I try to connect from the postfix box to itself, `/var/log/maillog` shows a connection attempt. When I try to connect from another machine (on the same LAN, ie. 192.168.1.x), nothing is output to `/var/log/maillog`. Also, I have set `mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8, 0/0` to no effect

Comment: rather than looking at your maillog, try tcpdump -n -i <iface> port 25, and then, try to connect. If your traffic is being blocked by some other box, you will not see it. If your traffic is blocked locally, then your problem is at the postfix box.

Comment: Also, after the line "-A INPUT -j REJECT ..." everithing is droped, subsequents rules in chain INPUT are completely ignored ans useless. SMTP only uses tcp, not udp. "-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT" accepts everything, even "-m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED".

Answer (score 3):

Gah, what a silly mistake. There was a problem in my `main.cf` file. I needed to set `inet_interfaces = all`. Before it was only accepting from `localhost`.

Comment: +1 Made the same mistake with `sendmail`. In `sendmail.cf` the line containing `DaemonPortOptions=` needs to have the ip address tweaked. `0.0.0.0` matches all interfaces.